# What does (0 &) mean in an evaluation?

Tags: syntax

My *Mathematica* code is this:

```
Simplify[D[Sqrt[1 + (u')^2 + (-60 x - 20 u u')^2], u]]
```

It returns this:

> `(1200 u x (0&) + (1200 x + (0&) + 400 u^2 (0&)) u^′+ 400 u (u')^2) / 
>    Sqrt[1 + (u^′)^2 + 400 (3 x + u u^′)^2]`

What does the `(0&)` term mean?

Comment: It's the zero function, equivalent to `f[x_] := 0`.

Comment: When you wrote `u` and `u'`, did you mean them to be two distinct variables?  In Mathematica, they are not.  `'` denotes the derivative.  `(u')` is assumed to be a function.  In *Mathematica*, `(u')^2` makes no sense and leads to the sorts of weird results you see here.

Comment: Yes, I meant them as two distinct variables. Perhaps that's why Mathematica responded as such. Evaluating the Euler-Lagrange equation for a given functional integrand f(x,u,u') requires computation of its partials wrt u and u'. It seems that I should have been more careful in setting this up than I was. In any case I can see the concern raised by @Szabolcs. And I appreciate the gentle treatment in this forum. I'll give the formulation another shot with commenters' observations in mind.

Answer (score 9):

Simpler example:

```
D[u', u]
(*  0 &  *)
```

Usually it helps to inspect the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of an expression to understand how *Mathematica* works.

```
u' // FullForm
```

[image]

But comparing the two similar forms, `Derivative[1][u]` and `x[1][u]`, it's hard to understand what is happening.

```
D[Derivative[1][u], u] // Trace
```

[image]

```
D[x[1][u], u] // Trace
```

[image]

```
D[x[1][u], u] /. x -> Derivative
(*  u''  *)

D[x[1][u] /. x -> Derivative, u]
(*  0 &  *)
```

The difference between these last two examples is hard for me to explain.  The first is probably because `Derivative[1]'` evaluates to `Derivative[2]`.  It may be a bug, I suppose.  If $u$ is a function of some variable $t$, then
$${d \over du}\,u' = {dt \over du}\,{d \over dt}\,u' = {u'' \over u'}\,.$$
But it's more like this:
$${d \over du}\,u'={d \over du}\,{du \over dt} \mathrel{\buildrel ? \over =} {d \over dt}\,{du \over du} = {d \over dt}\,1\,,$$
because of the following:

```
D[u', u] // Trace
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Although *Mathematica* has an interpretation for `D[u', u]` as discussed by Micheal E2, I have an hard time conceiving (i.e., have no clue) of a situation where using that form would apply. So I wonder if the following is what you really wanted is

```
D[Sqrt[1 + (u'[x])^2 + (-60 x - 20 u[x] u'[x])^2], x]
```

which gives

[image: form]

which is at least something that appears sensible to me.